# What happened when using same Storage account for multiple Azure WebJobs (dev/live)?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

In my small job, I just use same Storage Account for `AzureWebJobsDashboard` and `AzureWebJobsStorage` configs.

But what happened when we use same connection string for local Debugging and Published job equally? Are they treated in isolated manner? Or do they have any conflict issue?

I looked into blobs of published job and found `azure-webjobs-dashboad/functions/instances` or `azure-webjobs-dashboad/functions/recent/by-job-run/{jobname}`, or `azure-webjobs-hosts/output-logs` directories; they have no discriminator specified among jobs while some other directories have GUID with job name.

Note that my job will be run in continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or do they have any conflict issue?

No, there is no conflict issue. Base on my experience, it is **not** recommended to local debugging while Published job is running in the azure with the same connection string. Take Azure Storage queue for example, we can't control which queue should be executed in the local or in the azure.  If we try to use debug it locally, please have a try to **stop** the continue WebJob from Azure Portal.

[image]

If we try to know WebJob is executed from which instance we could log the instance info in the code with the environment variable  `WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID`.The following is the code sample:

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue")] string message, TextWriter log)
        {
            string instance = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID");
            string newMsg = $"WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID：{instance}, timestamp：{DateTime.Now}, Message：{message}";
            log.WriteLine(newMsg);
            Console.WriteLine(newMsg);

        }
```

More info  please refer to [how to use azure queue storage with the WebJob SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to). The following is snipped from the document.

> If your web app runs on multiple instances, a continuous WebJob runs on each machine, and each machine will wait for triggers and attempt to run functions. The WebJobs SDK queue trigger automatically prevents a function from processing a queue message multiple times; functions do not have to be written to be idempotent

**Update :**

About timer trigger we could find more explanation of timer trigger in the WebJob from the [GitHub document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions).So if you want to debug locally, please have a try to stop the WebJob from the azure portal.

> only a single instance of a particular timer function will be running across all instances (you don't want multiple instances to process the same timer event).

Comment: Thanks. I don't use `QueueTrigger`, but just use `TimerTrigger` only. In this case, there could be no conflict. am I right?

Comment: About  `TimerTrigger`, `a single instance of a particular timer function will be running across all instances.` So if you want to debug locally, please have a try to stop the  WebJob from the azure portal. I have updated the answer.

Comment: So we can say, `TimerTrigger` in dev can make live job NOT start as single instance is allowed by design. is it clear?

Comment: Yes. It just can be executed in one stance even if  WebApp scales to multiple instances.

Comment: what happen if we deploy multiple instances (with differents names) of the same webjob with the same AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage ? It seems there are conflicts preventing one the instance of the webjob to start (TimerTrigger).